# How to prevent background image being squeezed when the keyboard opens?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using `Xamarin.Forms` and is targeting `iOS` and `Android`.

Default view
[image: without keyboard]

Keyboard opened and the background image squeezed
[image: keyboard opened]

Background image squeezed as well in landscape mode
[image: Landscape]

**XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XilnexOTM.Views.LoginPage"
             BackgroundImage="bg1.png" >
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Text="PICTURE"  />
            <Label Text="PIC 2" />

            <Entry Placeholder="Username" />
            <Entry Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="true"/>

            <Button x:Name="btn_Login"
                    Text="Login"
                    BackgroundColor="#FF0000"/>

        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

---

Is there any possible way by applying the concept in `CSS` to `Xamarin.Forms` ?

```
xx {
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: right bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With `ContentPage.BackgroundImage` you can't control aspect ratio. Instead use `Image` combined with `AbsoluteLayout` (and set `Aspect` property of `Image`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XilnexOTM.Views.LoginPage">

    <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
            Source="bg1.png" Aspect="AspectFill"/>

        <ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Text="PICTURE"  />
                <Label Text="PIC 2" />

                <Entry Placeholder="Username" />
                <Entry Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="true"/>

                <Button x:Name="btn_Login"
                        Text="Login"
                        BackgroundColor="#FF0000"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>                   

    </AbsoluteLayout>             
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Or just use `Grid` instead of `AbsoluteLayout`. No need to have those extra properties setup

Comment: Great answer! The BackgroundImage property of ContentPage doesn't support adding aspect parameters. Also changing the BackgroundImage property of ContentPage crashes VS (community Mac) for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

Inside your MainActivity you can use AdjustPan or AdjustResize:

```
[Activity(WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan)]
public class MyActivity : Activity
{
   .....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer doing by code, here is my solution:

I always have my Device Screen like this in my App.xaml:

```
    public static double ScreenWidth { get; set; }
    public static double ScreenHeight { get; set; }
```

Then in my Android Main Activity:

```
        Passapp.App.ScreenWidth = (double)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
        Passapp.App.ScreenHeight = (double)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
```

And in my iOS AppDelegate:

```
App.ScreenWidth = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
        App.ScreenHeight = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height;
```

So when You have your Screen Width and Height you can do this in whatever page you have:

```
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{

    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

        var layout = new AbsoluteLayout();

#if __ANDROID__

        BackgroundImage = "Background";
#endif

#if __IOS__
        Image img = new Image()
        {
            Source = "Background",
            Aspect = Aspect.Fill
        };

        layout.Children.Add(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, App.ScreenWidth, App.ScreenHeight));
#endif


        Content = layout;
    }
}
```